# Unify select sql. Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I can unify the two select below in a single, where in the first column return the result of the first and second column the result of the second.

```
select count(*) from rrhh.empleado where fecha_contratado > current_date - interval '100 days'; // select1
select count(*) from rrhh.empleado where fecha_fin_contrato  > current_date - interval '100 days'; //select2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
with a as (
select 
  case when fecha_contratado > current_date - interval '100 days' then 1  
else 0 end q1
, case when fecha_fin_contrato  > current_date - interval '100 days' then 1 
else 0 end q2
from rrhh.empleado
)
select sum(q1), sum(q2)
from a
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical case for [conditional aggregation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
select count(*) filter (where fecha_contratado > current_date - interval '100 days'),
       count(*) filter (where fecha_fin_contrato > current_date - interval '100 days')
from   rrhh.empleado
```

You can use the `CASE` expression (and the fact that most aggregates does not use `NULL` values) for versions earlier than 9.4:

```
select count(case when fecha_contratado > current_date - interval '100 days' then 1 end),
       count(case when fecha_fin_contrato > current_date - interval '100 days' then 1 end)
from   rrhh.empleado
```

*Note*: these queries will scan the whole table, while your original queries *could* make use of indexes on `fecha_contratado` and `fecha_fin_contrato`. If performance matters to you, you *could* append a filter to these queries too:

```
where least(fecha_contratado, fecha_fin_contrato) > current_date - interval '100 days'
```

and you *could* index the expression: `least(fecha_contratado, fecha_fin_contrato)`.